# Rswag and Rspec: Undefined method for URL parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am working on a Rails project that uses Swagger through rswag and Rspec for testing.  The code is an API which needs to be tested through the Rspec system.  I am new to both rswag and Rspec.

My code works currently but it fails the provided Rspec tests.  The issue I am having is that Rspec reports:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `comment_id' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Comments::CommentsCommentId::Patch::CommentWithProvidedIdSetToSticky:0x000000000c3055a0>
```

comment_id is a parameter in the URL.  Here is the relevant Rswag/rspec definition:

```
path '/comments/{comment_id}' do
  parameter name: :comment_id, in: :path, type: :string, format: :uuid
  patch 'Sets the sticky comment for a given invoice, client or debtor id' do
    tags 'Comments'
    produces 'application/json'
    consumes 'application/json'
    security [oauth2: []]
    parameter name: :data, in: :body, required: true, schema: {
      type: :object,
      properties: {
        data: {
          type: :object,
          properties: {
            attributes: {
              type: :object,
              required: %i[comment_id],
              properties: {
                sticky_flag: { type: :boolean }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    response '201', 'comment with provided id set to sticky' do
      let(:data) { { comment_id: '', sticky_flag: '' } }
      run_test!
    end
```

Why am I getting the No Method error in the Rspec output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need add `let(:comment_id){ 'id' }` that 'id' you can create an record by FactoryBot like:
`let(:comment_id){ FactoryBot.create(:comment).id }`